# Passing/Updating Data in a Factory from One Controller to Another

Tags: angularjs, factory, angularjs-service

I'm not sure if I am having a "best practices" issue where I am trying to solve this challenge in a weird and wonderful way or wether my grip on AngularJS just isn't there yet.

**Scenario**: So I have been trying to come up with a way to have "originCity.cityName" be output on the page a few times, all referencing the same object inside the same factory with the hope that if I set it to some other value ("Test String" for example) then it would retroactively replace all of the `{{originCity.cityName}}` I have around the page.

```
module.service('cityFactory', function () {

    return {
        originCity: {
            cityName: 'TestLocation'
        };

        //Update the city
        this.update = function (newCityName) {
            this.originCity.cityName = newCityName;
        }
    });
```

In two seperate controllers I have the following call to the factory:

```
$scope.originCity = cityService.originCity
```

And, to demonstrate, in a seperate controller I have the following call to the update method of the factory:

```
$scope.setCity = function() {
    cityService.update('Test String');
}
```

As I mentioned above, this is very much new to me so I might be going about this all wrong but I was hoping to have a factory with a method that I can call from anywhere on the page (so long as the dependencies are all in line) to update that value in a few places.

If I `console.log` the `this.originCity.cityName` in the update method inside the factory then it outputs correctly as `Test String` but the other references to the data do not currently update.

Comment: How do you call the update method? If you place it in a `$watch`, it should update correctly

Comment: Oh wait, you update the factory.. missread that. In that case, how do you change the value? through an input box?

Comment: @Guinn for demonstration purposes I tried to keep it as simple as possible so I just put a random button on the page that if I press I call the update method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.factory('cityFactory', function () {
    var _cityName = null;
    var cityFactoryInstance = {};

    //Update the city from outside the DOM:
    var _update = function (newCityName) {
        _cityName = newCityName;
    }

    cityFactoryInstance.update = _update;
    cityFactoryInstance.cityName = _cityName;
    return cityFactoryInstance;
});

module.controller('controller1',
    ['$scope','cityFactory', function ($scope, cityFactory) {

        $scope.originCity.cityName = cityFactory.cityName;
    }]);

module.controller('controller2',
    ['$scope', 'cityFactory', function ($scope, cityFactory) {

        $scope.originCity.cityName = cityFactory.cityName;
    }]);
```

In DOM:

```
{{originCity.cityName}}
```