# angularJS: share filtered data between controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

Sharing data between controllers is a topic discussed a lot here and I solved it by creating a `factory` that holds functions to call our API and of course returns our data.

```
angular.factory('polygonService', ['$resource', polygonService]);

function polygonService($resource) {


    var service = {

        data: [],

        api: $resource(
            'url', 
            {
                cityID: '@id'
            }, 
            {
                get: { 
                    method: 'JSONP', 
                    params: {
                        callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
                    }
                }
            }
        )


    }


    return service;

}
```

Now, the `data` in this service is displayed on a map and in a list. These are two separate directives & controllers.

The list directive enables the user to filter the data by various properties but the filtered data is only available inside the $scope of the list directive.

How can I make the filtered data available to the $scope of the map controller?

Do I have to make a `filteredData` property inside the service and $watch for that from the map controller too?

Comment: Take a look for my answer in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975516/passing-updating-data-in-a-factory-from-one-controller-to-another/30975802#30975802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to expose the filtered results through the service, but you don't need to watch that.

Set a scope variable in your controller to your service

```
$scope.polygonService = polygonService;
```

Then, you can access $scope.polygonService.filteredData from your controller, or polygonService.filteredData from your view and the two way binding will work as expected.

```
<li ng-repeat="data in polygonService.filteredData">
  {{ data }}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need a `$watch` to update the $scope variables of my second directive, the map. It won't just update when the service data changes, sadly. But yeah that's but I figured.

Comment: Could you provide a plunker?

Comment: "You will need to expose the filtered results through the service"
half a year later i know what you meant by that.
Pretty much `return data` or a variation of that. And filter the data inside the service - then return that data - maybe through a `getData` method.