# how to make a global variables in single controller and call function inside factory in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a global variable that can be access in a same controller. I want to **data variable** should be global so that I can access it from anywhere within a controller. My code is :-

```
var enterprise = angular.module('EnterpriseCtrl',[]);
    enterprise.controller('EnterpriseController',function($scope,$routeParams,$http,$location,Enterprise){

    $scope.enterpriseSubmit = function(){
             $scope.enterprise.sector_id = $scope.enterprise.select_sector.id;
             var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
              reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onloadend = function(e){
              var data  = e.target.result;
               }
              reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
              var enterprise = Enterprise.insert($scope.enterprise,$rootScope.file);
                enterprise.success(function(response){
                   if(response.data !=""){
                         $location.path('/enterprises');
                   }else alert('Data not saved.');
                });
        };

    });
```

and second things is that when I get success response after that can we send another $http.post request in **enterprise.success function**. Something like this :-

```
enterprise.success(function(response){
   if(response.data !=""){
       $http.post("http://5.17.18.10:3030/api/login",{status:'1'}).success(function (response) 
          {
              console.log(response);
           });
          $location.path('/enterprises');
     }else alert('Data not saved.');
```

Comment: Here is your solution in an older post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975516/passing-updating-data-in-a-factory-from-one-controller-to-another/30975802#30975802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller has a scope, thus defining a variable within a controller makes it accessable everywhere in that controller. A global variable would mean that it is accesable in other controllers aswell. So I'm not sure if you want to have a global variable or a variable within the scope of a controller. If you want to use a variable in views (like with `ng-model`) you can define the variable as `$scope.data`.

You defined the `var data` in a function though, if you want it to be accessable outside the function, you should first declare the `var data` in the controller and then use that variable (without re-declaring) in your function.

Your other question about a post in a successfunction of another post, yeah it can be done. Did you try it before asking? :-) Instead of `.success()` you might want to use `.then()`, but for reference about that you can read [this](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http). The only problem that can occur is, the posts are done asynchonously. So it might not return the data in an order you would want it to be returned. (because the code that the initial post is called from will continue while the post is executed asynchronously).

I hope this answers your questions.

**Update**
You could use `$rootScope`, but this isn't the best practise. The best practise is to store the variable in your factory or service (as stated in other answers, service is the way to go for variables you want to access in other controllers) and then call on the variable in your success function.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually I want to store some value in data variable after that I want to use in success function. when I call it, it's says variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

To get your variable `data` global, and to access it into differents controllers, you should us **Service**. Why ? Because Service are **Singletons**, they share the same instance.

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service(){

    var data = '';

    this.set = function(d){
      data = d;
    }

    this.get = function(){
      return data;
    }

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .service('Share', Service);

})();
```

**Controller 1**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Share) {

  $scope.data = 3;

  Share.set($scope.data);

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Controller 2**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Share) {

  console.log(Share.get())

}

angular
.module('app')
.controller('ctrl2', Controller);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Paul Boutes example is a good one.  To expand on it a bit, the reason it's global is because it's a singleton, and it can be **injected into any other module/service/factory**.  Also you may want to use min-safe syntax to ensure that the code can be minified without problems.

In any case, Angular allows you to create a module and require it in any other service or factory, shown below where **module.b requires module.a** in the array on the angular.module line.

> use-as-global.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('module.a', [])
            .service('UseAsGlobal', function () {
                this.foo = 'foo';
            });
})();
```

> some-module.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('module.b', ['module.a'])
        .controller('SomeController', ['$scope', 'UseAsGlobal', function($scope, UseAsGlobal) {
            $scope.doSomethingWithFoo = function() {
                console.log('this is UseAsGlobalsFoo ', UseAsGlobal.foo);
            };

            $scope.changeFoo = function() {
                UseAsGlobal.foo = 'bar';
            };
        }])
        .service('SomeService', ['UseAsGlobal', function (UseAsGlobal) {
            this.sayFoo = function () {
                console.log(UseAsGlobal.foo);
            };
        }]);
```

})();